# Assign a login to a user created without login (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have got a user in my database that hasn't got an associated login.  It seems to have been created without login.

Whenever I attempt to connect to the database with this user I get the following error:

```
Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
The server principal "UserName" is not able to access the database 
"DatabaseName" under the current security context.
```

I'd like to specify a login for this user so that I can actually use it to access the database.  I've tried the following script to associate a login with the user.

```
USE [DatabaseName]
ALTER USER [UserName]
WITH LOGIN = [UserName]
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Msg 33016, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The user cannot be remapped to a login. Remapping can only be done for users 
that were mapped to Windows or SQL logins.
```

Is there any way I can assign a login to this user?  I'd like to not have to start from scratch because this user has a lot of permissions that would need setting up again.

**Edit:** in response to Philip Kelley's question, here's what I get when I run `select * from sys.database_principals where name = 'username'`.

[image: SQL User]

Apologies for the size of the image, you'll need to open it in a new tab to view it properly.

**Edit2:**

Ok, I've dropped the existing LOGIN as suggested by gbn, and I'm using the following script to create a new LOGIN with same SID as the user.

```
CREATE LOGIN [UserName] 
WITH PASSWORD=N'Password1', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[DatabaseName], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, 
CHECK_POLICY=OFF, 
SID=0x0105000000000009030000001139F53436663A4CA5B9D5D067A02390
```

It's now giving me the following error message, it appears that the SID is too long for the LOGIN's SID field.

```
Msg 15419, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Supplied parameter sid should be binary(16).
```

Am I up the creek without a paddle?

Comment: See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55769/sql-server-fix-users

Comment: @HenrikHolmgaardHøyer look at the question dates.  This one is from 2011, and the other is from 2012.  The other question is "newer" so that one is the duplicate, not this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have an orphaned user and this can't be remapped with ALTER USER (yet) becauses there is no login to map to. So, you need run [CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) first.

If the database level user is

- a Windows Login, the mapping will be fixed automatcially via the AD SID
- a SQL Login, use "sid" from [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx) for the SID option for the login

Then run ALTER USER

Edit, after comments and updates

The sid from sys.database_principals is for a Windows login.

So trying to create and re-map to a SQL Login will fail

Run this to get the Windows login

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(0x0105000000000009030000001139F53436663A4CA5B9D5D067A02390)
```

Comment: I've tried running CREATE LOGIN (which was succesful) but when I then try to alter the user to map to the new LOGIN I still get the same error message: 'The user cannot be remapped to a login. Remapping can only be done for users 
that were mapped to Windows or SQL logins.'

Comment: What CREATE LOGIN did you use please?

Comment: I did it via the SSMS "New Login..." button, the generated script was: CREATE LOGIN [UserName] WITH PASSWORD=N'Password1', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[DatabaseName], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF

Comment: Drop it, and use the SID option

Comment: Ok, I've dropped the login as you suggest and I'm attempting to create a new one specifying the SID, I now have the following error: Supplied parameter sid should be binary(16).  I've edited the question and provided more details including the script that I'm using.

Comment: That SID is for a Windows login. Try `SELECT SUSER_SNAME(0x0105000000000009030000001139F53436663A4CA5B9D5D067A02390)` to find the details.

Comment: Hmmm... I get NULL back.  This is pretty weird.

Comment: When you ran CREATE LOGIN [UserName] ... what was the sid in sys.server_principals. You'll see the SQL vs WIndows difference. If this returns NULL, it means the Windows group does not exist, different domain, or different workgroup machine...

Comment: The SID I got when I ran the CREATE LOGIN [UserName]... statement was 0xBD270CB70864504FAFBB231C1839A5E3.  There isn't an entry in the  sys.server_principals table that matches the SID of the user.

Comment: I know, but note the SID pattern is *way* different. As per my last comment, you can't unorphan this user in the current environment. Fact.

Comment: So I'm up the creek then.  Thanks for your help, I'll mark you as the answer.  I suppose "it's not possible" is still an answer :-)

Comment: Thank you. I'll explain more. If SQL Server can't resolve the SID it means you couldn't create the login anyway: it checks AD to get name from SID (SUSER_SNAME), and SID from name (CREATE LOGIN)

Comment: So I'd suppose the SID must a local SID from a different server.  Our servers are all on the same domain, so that's the only reasonable cause I can think of for the SID not being recognised.

Comment: You could try backtracking to machine portion of the SID http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier#Decoding_Machine_SID YMMV of course

Answer (score 93):

`sp_change_users_login` is deprecated.

Much easier is:

```
ALTER USER usr1 WITH LOGIN = login1;
```

Comment: Read the question, that's the first thing I tried and it yielded the following error: `Msg 33016, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The user cannot be remapped to a login. Remapping can only be done for users that were mapped to Windows or SQL logins.`

Comment: Dealing with old software here, these deprecated ways are still necessary to be aware of when porting old database over.

Comment: I know this answer didn't help answer the original question, however this did work for me.

Answer (score 51):

I found that this question was still relevant but not clearly answered in my case.

Using SQL Server 2012 with an orphaned SQL_USER this was the fix;

```
USE databasename                      -- The database I had recently attached
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'   -- Display orphaned users
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'UserName', NULL, 'Password'
```

Comment: Very useful option. Worked perfectly on orphaned user account +1.

Comment: If anyone scrolls through this is absolutely the answer to the OP. I had an orphaned user brought into a new SQL install on a machine where a backup was restored. The user didn't have an actual login, but modifying the last line above in the _UserName_ and _Password_ values made the orphaned login now legitimate and work properly.

Comment: This will work for a real orphaned user, but doesn't do anything if the user is of the type 'SQL user without login'

Comment: @DavidGardiner I don't know if it was real orphaned user or not, but I had a DB user shown as "SQL user without login" in Properties after restore, and this procedure worked for me. It was MSSQL 2014.

Comment: Users where sys.database_principals.authentication_type = 0 or 1 (and possibly others) show up in the SSMS dialog as "SQL user without login" however the type = 0's apparently cannot be re-linked.

Comment: Worked for me. I was getting crazy to change a Database User (not a Login) password and this worked like a charm!!!

Comment: you little beauty, go to the top of the dba class, thank you

Comment: Perfect, this fixed user without a login

Comment: I just want to confirm this worked for SQL Server 2017. one of our database users referred to a login/sid that was no longer valid. The Auto_fix linked the user to the valid login. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Through trial and error, it seems if the user was originally created "without login" then this query

```
select * from sys.database_principals
```

will show authentication_type = 0 (NONE).

Apparently these users cannot be re-linked to any login (pre-existing or new, SQL or Windows) since this command:

```
alter user [TempUser] with login [TempLogin]
```

responds with the Remap Error "Msg 33016" shown in the question.

Also these users do not show up in classic (deprecating) SP report:

```
exec sp_change_users_login 'Report'
```

If anyone knows a way around this or how to change authentication_type, please comment.

Comment: In my case my user is orphaned because of a db restore (came with the database). In this case `authentication_type = 1`

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database user is it? Run `select * from sys.database_principals` in the database and check columns `type` and `type_desc` for that `name`. If it is a Windows or SQL user, go with @gbn's answer, but if it's something else (which is my untested guess based on your error message) then you have a different problem.

---

Edit

So it is a SQL-authenticated login. Back when we'd use `sp_change_users_login` to fix such logins. SQL 2008 has it as "don't use, will be deprecated", which means that the ALTER USER command should be sufficient... but it might be worth a try in this case. Used properly (it's been a while), I believe this updates the SID of the User to match that of the login.

Comment: Have edited my question with the results you requested, you'll need to open the image in a new tab to read it properly.

Comment: I've already tried using sp_change_users_login, I get the following error: `"Terminating this procedure. The User name 'UserName' is absent or invalid."`  The SQL I'm using is `sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', @UserNamePattern='UserName', @LoginName='LoginName';`

Answer (score 0):

Create a login for the user

Drop and re-create the user, WITH the login you created.

There are other topics discussing how to replicate the permissions of your user.
I recommend that you take the opportunity to define those permissions in a Role and call sp_addrolemember to add the user to the Role.