# how to deal with "remapping can only be done for users that were mapped to Windows or SQL logins"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, bacpac

**The scenario:**

Trying to restore from a bacpac taken from SQL Azure.

Either to a new SQL Azure database instance, or an on premises server. For the earlier with the Management portal or the [DAC Framework Client Side Tools](http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Import%20Export%20Client%20Side%20Tools&referringTitle=Home).

It seems to work fine, and naturally the SQL users are not mapped to SQL logins after the restore.

**What I tried:**

When I try to map it with: 
`alter user MyUser with login = MyLogin`, it fails with:

> Msg 33016, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The user cannot be remapped to a login. Remapping can only be done for users that were mapped to Windows or SQL logins.

Running `select * from sys.database_principals` does list the users, but with a much longer SID than a SQL authenticated user I created to compare it to.

On premises if I run a `sp_change_users_login 'Report'` the users are **Not** listed, so are not being detected as **orphaned**.

On premises if I try using **sp_change_users_login**, it fails with:

> Msg 15291, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_change_users_login, Line 114 Terminating this procedure. The User name 'MyUser' is absent or invalid.

On premises if I try it through the User Mapping section of the Login Properties UI, I get:

> Create failed for User 'My User'. ... User, group, or role 'MyUser'
>   already exists in the current database.

I tried doing it all over again, in case something [was corrupted](http://www.sqlmag.com/forums/aft/96868) when restoring for some reason, same results.

**The question:**

How can I remap these SQL Users?

I'd like to avoid having to re-create those from scratch and any relation those have to the schema objects in the database?

**Some extra info:**

One type of SQL users that look a lot like what I'm seeing for the SQL Azure users, are ones created with

`create user AnotherUser without login`

Those fail in the exact same way in all the 3 mapping approaches I used above. That is not the case in any of the approaches for regular SQL users. Additionally the sid is also long, and begins with the same "0x010500000000000903000000"

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468813/assign-a-login-to-a-user-created-without-login-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment117920735_6468813

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you ever get that, **it is Most likely a corrupt backup**. Just like the linked on [premises scenario](http://www.sqlmag.com/forums/aft/96868), the behaviour comes out of nowhere and was traced to a corrupt backup.

In my case, it was the same. Right before posting the question, my last try was: **a different backup of the database, it worked without issues**.

Answer (score 5):

A [sqlmatters article](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Orphaned%20Users%20vs%20Users%20Without%20Logins.aspx) explains that

> A user without login is a special type of user that has deliberately
>   been set up without an associated login.

one can check if it is such a case by examining the SID:

```
 -- SQL to run to identify users without login :
SELECT CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(sid) = 28
             AND type = 'S'       -- only want SQL users
             AND principal_id > 4 -- ignore built in users
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_user_without_login,*
FROM sys.database_principals
```

where users without login have longer SID than regular (orphaned) users.

These special users cannot be mapped to a login because they are made that way. Someone must have intentionally or by mistake created a user `WITHOUT LOGIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find users that can be mapped to a login with the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.database_principals
WHERE 1=1
    AND [type] = 'S'
    AND [name] NOT IN ('dbo','guest','INFORMATION_SCHEMA','sys')
    AND authentication_type_desc IN ('WINDOWS','INSTANCE')
```