# How can I connect ADFS to a SQL database that's on a different domain?

Tags: sql-server, adfs

We have 2 domains. The first one contains technical servers, database, etc., the second one contains supporting servers. They can't trust each other (company rules). When configuring ADFS in domain 2, I need to connect to a SQL 2016 database in domain 1. But the ADFS connection uses Windows Authentication and as a result I get an error.
I create scripts:
`Export-AdfsDeploymentSQLScript -DestinationFolder "C:\SQLScript" –ServiceAccountName Domain2\ADFS`
*CreateDB.sql* works fine, but *Set-Permissions.sql* completed with errors

> Msg 15004, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_validname, Line 61, Name cannot be NULL.

I think this is because he didn't find a user with the same sid. Right?
In SQL script it is like this:

> DECLARE @hex_account_sid varbinary(85)
> SET @hex_account_sid =0x010500000000000515000000EDF2C8FA8D26A855458E07EB50040000
>
> DECLARE @service_account sysname
> SELECT @service_account = SUSER_SNAME(@hex_account_sid)

I thought it might be possible to create a user with the same sid
`CREATE LOGIN adfs_service with password='123456' , SID = 0x010500000000000515000000EDF2C8FA8D26A855458E07EB50040000;`
but got an error

> Msg 15419, Supplied parameter sid should be binary(16).

So my question are:

1. How can I configure ADFS to use SQL authentication?
   **or**
2. How can I create the correct permission?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS does not support other authentication methods - only integrated security. ADFS will use the credentials for the database connection which is configured for ADFS windows service. Generally you can connect SQL servers in another domain using windows authentication. Kindly check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468813/assign-a-login-to-a-user-created-without-login-sql-server) for the error message that you are getting and see if it helps